# YII2 Double model validation in Active Form

Tags: php, validation, yii, yii2

i`m new in this community and I just start to write web apps with yii.

I have a problem with combining 2 different models in one form.
I have the following code:

```
 <?php

use yii\helpers\Html;
use yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm;
use yii\helpers\ArrayHelper;
use app\models\Company;
use app\models\Hosting;

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $website app\models\Website */
/* @var $hosting app\models\Hosting */
/* @var $form yii\bootstrap\ActiveForm */
?>
<div class="website-form">
    <?php
        $form = ActiveForm::begin([
            'layout' => 'horizontal',
            'options' =>
                [
                    'enctype' => 'multipart/form-data',
                    'class' => 'well',
                ],
        ])
    ?>
    <?php
        $companyOpdions = ['prompt' => ''];
        if(isset(Yii::$app->request->queryParams['company_id'])) {
            $companyOpdions['disabled'] = true;
        }
        $hostingList = ArrayHelper::map(Hosting::find()->select(['id', 'name'])->where(['approved' => 'Yes'])->all(), 'id', 'name');
        $hostingList['addAdditionalHosting'] = Yii::t('app', 'Add Additional Hosting');
    ?>
    <?=
        $form->field($website, 'company_id')->dropDownList(
            ArrayHelper::map(Company::find()->select(['id', 'name'])->where(['user_id' => \Yii::$app->user->id])->all(), 'id', 'name'),
            $companyOpdions
        )->label(Yii::t('app', 'Company'))
    ?>
    <?= $form->field($website, 'hosting_id')->dropDownList($hostingList, ['prompt' => ''])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Hosting')) ?>
        <div id="addAdditionalHostingContainer" class="form-group" style="display:none;">
            <div class="text-center">
                <?= $form->field($hosting, 'name')->textInput(['readonly' => true])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Hosting Name')) ?>
                <?= $form->field($hosting, 'domain')->textInput(['readonly' => true])->label(Yii::t('app', 'Hosting Domain')) ?>
                <?= Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Cancel'), null, ['class' => 'btn btn-primary', 'id' => 'cancelAdditionalHostingButton']) ?>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?= $form->field($website, 'url')->textInput(['maxlength' => 255]) ?>
    <?= $form->field($website, 'incomingMonthlyTraffic')->textInput() ?>
    <div class="form-group">
        <?= Html::submitButton($website->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') : Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $website->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-lg btn-block btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
    </div>
    <?php ActiveForm::end(); ?>
</div>
<?php
    $this->registerJs("$(document).ready(function () {

        $('#website-hosting_id').on('change', function() {
            if($(this).val() == 'addAdditionalHosting') {
                $('#website-hosting_id').prop('disabled', true);
                $('#website-hosting_id').attr('disabled', true);
                $('#hosting-name').prop('readonly', false);
                $('#hosting-domain').attr('readonly', false);
                $(this).parents('.form-group').hide();
                $('#addAdditionalHostingContainer').show('slow');
            }
        });

        $('#cancelAdditionalHostingButton').on('click', function() {
            $('#hosting-name').prop('readonly', true);
            $('#hosting-domain').attr('readonly', true);
            $('#website-hosting_id').prop('disabled', false);
            $('#website-hosting_id').attr('disabled', false);
            $('#website-hosting_id').parents('.form-group').show();
            $('#addAdditionalHostingContainer').hide('slow');
        });

    });");
?>
```

The idea is: you can choose form list of hosts or you can add another.
The problem is  the JS validation is already generated and when i choose some host from list.
I can`t submit the form because validation is validating this hidden fields.

Comment: Could you update your question to provide the validation rules as well?

Comment: It's not normal, Please keep Backend codes separate from of view, You need a model and a view and a controller, Don't develop DB connection on view file's, Keep separate  on model, Try to pass variables and value from controller to views, For your work, You just need multi model forms in Yii2. Check http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567736/yii2-multiple-forms-in-a-single-action link.

Comment: If you need to edit a complex object, consider using JsonSchema and some kind of editor (Example: http://jeremydorn.com/json-editor/).

Answer (score 0):

I think You need to use **when** in your validation code,Example:

```
['Field1', 'required', 'when' => function ($model) {
      return $model->Feild2 == 'VALUE';
},   'whenClient' => "function (attribute, value) {
return $('#FORMID-Field2').val() == 'value';
}"],
```

Note: as guys said above, you shouldn't include such logic in your view, for example you are checking for GET params inside the view, this is wrong. such code should be inside the controller.