# yii2: delete values in two tables using single controller action?

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I have two tables table1 and table2 and I am trying to delete row in these two table.I have same values on both table but id is different so i tried like this, 
my controller,

```
 public function actionDelete($id)
 {
 $this->findModel($id);
 $select = Employee::find()
            ->select('Name')
            ->where(['Id' => $id])
            ->all();
$deluser=Employee::find()->where(['Id' => $id])->one()->delete() AND User::find()->where(['Name' =>$select])->one();
$deluser->delete();
 return $this->redirect(['index','select'=>$select]);
}
```

pls anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: pls put it back, what you have change in your question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Employee class is object.

Try this:

```
public function actionDelete($id)
{
    $this->findModel($id);
    $select = Employee::find()
                ->select('Name')
                ->where(['Id' => $id])
                ->all();

    Employee::find()->where(['id' => $id])->one()->delete();

    User::find()->where(['id' =>$id])->one()->delete();

    return $this->redirect(['index','select'=>$select]);
}
```

Comment: I tried this way but   PHP Fatal Error – yii\base\ErrorException
Call to a member function delete() on a non-object
getting this error

Comment: both table have different id value so i can't delete using $id in  user table. But both table have column Name and same value so , how to find name in employee table using $id and based on that name ,delete row in the user table.

Comment: Why name? why not use some kind of relation, like put user id into employee table as foreign key?

Comment: ok i created employee id in user table as foreign key instead of you said then how to change my delete query?

Comment: what is field name in user table?
`User::find()->where(['employee_id' =>$id])->one()->delete();`

Comment: employee_id is the field name in both tables.But id value is different in both tables so pls tell me how to delete using employee_id in both tables.

Comment: Thank u so much sir , i can delete now in both tables. One more help can i do like this for updation is it possible?

Comment: Yes you can.[Pls check](http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/291/update-two-models-with-one-view/)

Comment: No, using single update form that is same like delete.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567736/yii2-multiple-forms-in-a-single-action

Comment: pls put it back, what you have change in your question, create new question if you are unable to solve your issue.

Comment: ok... i put my question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37850891