# yii2: Update values in two tables using single controller action?

Tags: php, yii2-basic-app

I have two tables table1 and table2 and I am trying to update row in these two table.I have same values on both table but id is different so i tried like this, 
my controller,

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
  {
   $model = $this->findModel($id);
   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model-     >validate()) {
         Employee::find()->where(['Id' => $id])->one()->update();
         User::find()->where(['User_id' =>$id])->one()->update();
         if ( $model->save()) { 
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
         }
    } else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,]);
    }
}
```

I have table like this

CREATE TABLE `Employee` ( `Id` int(11) NOT NULL,`Company_company_id` int(100) NOT NULL,`Company_name` varchar(100) NOT NULL, `Employee_id` int(100) NOT NULL, `Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`Email_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`Password` varchar(16) NOT NULL,`Joining_date` date NOT NULL,`Confirmation_date` date NOT NULL, `Relieving_date` date NOT NULL,`Leaves_Available` int(25) NOTNULL,`Status`enum('Active','Inactive') NOT NULL,)

CREATE TABLE `User` (`Id` int(15) NOT NULL,
`Name` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`Email_id` varchar(100) NOT NULL,`Password` varchar(16) NOT NULL,`Status` enum('Active','Inactive') NOT NULL,)

I tried like this but i can't update both table
pls anyone help me
Thanks in advance

Comment: What is error message???

Comment: pls post your both model's name.

Comment: Employee() and User() are my models.

Answer (score 0):

Try This :

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
  {

   if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->validate()) 
   {
        $modelEmp= Employee::find()->where(['Id' => $id])->one();
        $modelUser= User::find()->where(['User_id' =>$id])->one();

        $modelEmp->Name=$_POST['name']; // use your field names
        $modelEmp->Email_id=$_POST['email_id'];

        $modelUser->Name=$_POST['name'];
        $modelUser->Email_id=$_POST['email_id'];

         if ( $modelEmp->save() && $modelUser->save()) { 
            return $this->redirect(['index']);
         }
    }
    else {
        return $this->render('update', [
            'model' => $model,]);
    }
}
```

Comment: I added with my question.

Comment: I tried like this but i am getting error,

 PHP Notice – yii\base\ErrorException
 Undefined index: name

Comment: use your field names as  you use in your form

Comment: <?= $form->field($model, 'Name')->textInput(['options' =>['name' =>'name','id' =>'name']]) ?>
 <?= $form->field($model, 'Email_id')->input('email',['options' =>['name' =>'email_id','id' =>'email_id']]) ?>

I gave like this .

Comment: try to check your POST data in your controller

Comment: I gave as per your answer.

Comment: Getting error like
Bad Request (#400)
Missing required parameters: id

Answer (score 0):

Here is simple example how I made savings to different tables from one controller.

```
    public function actionCreatesolo()
{
    $model = new Productordergroup();
    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model->save()) {

        $id = $model['product_id'];  //get selected product id
        $product = Product::findOne($id); //find product by selected id
        $product->grouped = '1';  //update value "groped" from 0 to 1
        $product->save(); //Save changes
        return $this->redirect(['view', 'id' => $model->id]); 
    }

    return $this->render('createsolo', [
        'model' => $model,
    ]);
}
```