# how to insert data to 2 tables from single form and controller in yii2

Tags: php, yii2

this is my create page

questions/create.php

```
<?php $form = ActiveForm::begin(); ?>
<br><br><br>
<?= $form->field($model, 'question')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

<?= $form->field($model, 'topic')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>
<?= $form->field($model1, 'askid')->textInput(['maxlength' => true]) ?>

 <div class="form-group">
  <?= Html::submitButton($model->isNewRecord ? Yii::t('app', 'Create') :   Yii::t('app', 'Update'), ['class' => $model->isNewRecord ? 'btn btn-success' : 'btn btn-primary']) ?>
  </div>

<?php ActiveForm::end();
```

askid is the field in another table askquestions

questioncontroller

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Questions();
    $model1 = new Askquestions();

     //$model1 -> load(Yii::$app->request->post());



    if ($model1->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //$model->user_id=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
         if($model1->save())
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
     } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model, 'model1' => $model1,
        ]);
    }
   }
```

i have generated model and crud for askquestions table and also included class in the controller and view page but the data is not inserting in the table what would be the possible way

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Yii2 multiple forms in a single action](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28567736/yii2-multiple-forms-in-a-single-action)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The possible solution would be: (not tested)

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    $model = new Questions();
    $model1 = new Askquestions();

    if ($model->load(Yii::$app->request->post()) && $model1->load(Yii::$app->request->post())) {
        //$model->user_id=Yii::$app->user->identity->id;
         if($model->save() && $model1->save())
        return $this->redirect(['index']);
     } else {
        return $this->render('create', [
            'model' => $model, 'model1' => $model1,
        ]);
    }
   }
```

Try the above code once.

But the best Solution for this problem will be creating and Form Model same like LoginForm it will have all the attributes in single form and validations can be applied on  in single model. Once everything is posted and validated then  you can save the values to the respective models

Comment: i have tried the alternative one you suggested by adding a  dummy column in the present working model and succeded